# Python/Pygame Error "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

I Made a platformer game with a second file with the level map in it. Now I want to change that it loads the level map from a text document. But I always get the error

```
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable.
```

When I print it, I see it read the document, but I still get the error in line 12.

````
def setup_world(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9):
    global level_map
    i = 0
    on = True
    top = True
    mid = False
    bot = False
    while on:
        if top:
            level_top = l1[i] + l2[i] + l3[i]   # Error Here
            level_map.append(level_top)
            i += 1
            if i == 32:
                i = 0
                top = False
                mid = True
        if mid:
            level_mid = l4[i] + l5[i] + l6[i]
            level_map.append(level_mid)
            i += 1
            if i == 32:
                i = 0
                mid = False
                bot = True
        if bot:
            level_bot = l7[i] + l8[i] + l9[i]
            level_map.append(level_bot)
            i += 1
            if i == 32:
                i = 0
                bot = False
                on = False

level_1 = open('textdatei.txt','r')     #I Tried this
```
````

Comment: `open` gives you a file descriptor. If you want to work with data, then you need to read the content with methods like `read()` or `readlines()`

Comment: That was easier then i thought. Thank you for that. Now i just get "string index out of range". But thats okay, i was just annoyed from this _io.TextIOWrapper error. I guess maybe i can handle the next error. Is there a difference between read and readlines?

Comment: `read` gives you the full content as a string / bytes as per your read flag. `readlines` gives you a list of string by splitting the content using newline character.

Answer (score 0):

You can't index `(__getitem__)` a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object. What you can do is work with a list of lines. Try this in your code:

```
lst = open(input("Input file name: "), "r").readlines()
```

Also, you aren't closing the file object, this would be better:

```
with open(input("Input file name: ", "r") as lst:
    print(medianStrat(lst.readlines()))
```

with ensures that file get closed, see docs

Comment: Thank you for that, i dont understand the thing with closing. When i use it i get "Invalid syntax" in the first of the two lines. do i need something else for that ?

Comment: Its a typo. Use it like `with open(input("Input file name: "), "r") as lst:`